# Лексические единицы

Tags: глаголы

Задалась вопросом (после спора с одним человеком): если у нас, например, есть два похожих слова, формы одного глагола, скажем, борИтесь и борЕтесь, то не важно ведь, что они от одного глагола - сам факт изменения буквы, значения и т.п. уже же превращает их в две разных лексических единицы, проще говоря - это же разные слова? Ни в коем случае же нельзя уже их назвать одним словом? Спасибо)

Comment: А в чем состоял спор-то? Из серии "брито или стрижено"? Вам с вашим собеседником надо было просто договориться, что вы, в вашем узком кругу, будете считать "одним словом", а что словами разными. Академическая наука вам тут не поможет, ибо она оперирует совсем другими понятиями. Таким, например, как словоформа. Если вы с ним не знакомы, то ваш спор академически бессодержателен.

Comment: behemothus, спасибо) Теперь разобрались) Т.е. с академической точки зрения это у нас просто словоформы одного и того же слова (лексемы), а вот с этой точки зрения разные: "Если данное понятие исследуется через призму функции общения, то с соответствующей точки зрения слово обычно видится как наименьший значимый сегмент потока речи."